# Can't log in to Heroku through CLI, after successfully logging in it won't let me enter any other commands

Tags: heroku, git-bash

I'm using Windows 10 and Git Bash for my CLI. I have tried logging in through the default browser pop up as well as using $ heroku login -i to force a login using the CLI. Both have the same result, it says I have successfully logged in but the cursor just sits flashing under where it says I'm logged in and any command entered is ignored, it just advances to the next line.

[CLI Window showing stuck cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmqyn.jpg)

I have made sure I am on the latest version of Git Bash (v2.34.1) and the heroku cli is also up to date (v7.59.2). I have also uninstalled and reinstalled Git Bash.

I did see a similar post where the same thing was happening to someone and they said they could login through the windows terminal and they were going to try uninstalling/reinstalling git bash but they never followed up with whether that worked or not (it didn't for me). I also was able to successfully login using the windows terminal but I'm just curious if there is a known fix for this issue so I can keep using git bash.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want to use git bash and not just git commands in a typical VSCode / Cmd prompt

Comment: I guess I don't really have a preference, was just watching a demo video and this was how they were doing it so I figured I would try it the same way

Comment: Try just using your terminal from VSCode or Command prompt and let me know if it works for you

Comment: It works fine through the terminal on VSCode as well as windows terminal so its something specific to git-bash